# run superclasses overridden function

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass, super

How does one call an overridden function in a superclass from the function which is overriding in the sublcass?

ex: class super has a function called foo, which is overridden in a subclass called sub, how would one make subs foo call supers foo?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage inheritance!

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        // do some base class foo-ing
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        // do some subclass foo-ing

        // to call the super-class foo:
        A::Foo( );
    }
};

void main()
{
    B obj;
    obj.Foo( );

    // This is if you want to call the base class Foo directly using the instance obj
    A* handle = &obj;
    handle->Foo( );
}
```

Comment: I do not want to simply be able to run the relevent foo, I want to run the super, and then other stuff in the sub class

Comment: I updated my post to include the base-class call in the method, which allows you to do exactly what you are describing. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are talking about overrides, rather than overloads. A qualified call to a function won't use the dynamic dispatch mechanism and you can control what override to pick:

```
struct base {
   virtual void foo() {...}
};
struct derived : base {
   virtual void foo() {
      base::foo();           // call the override at 'base' level
      ...
   }
};
```

If you are really talking about overloads, you can use the same mechanism, or you could bring the overloads into scope in the derived type:

```
struct base {
   void foo(int);
};
struct derived : base {
   using base::foo;           // make all overloads of base::foo available here
   void foo(double);
   void f() { base::foo(1); } // alternatively qualify the function call
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use super::foo. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    void foo(void)
    {
        printf("Class A\n");
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo(void)
    {
        printf("Class B\n");
        A::foo();
    }
};

int main ()
{
    B b;
    b.foo();
}
```